# angularstrap typeahead using object

Tags: typeahead, angular-strap

I am getting error when I try to use bs-typeahead on an object. The error message gets displayed when I start typing in the text box

Below is the html:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-lg"  id="city" name="city" ng-model="data.cityState" placeholder="City" ng-options="subscribedTown.id as subscribedTown.label  for (index, subscribedTown) in data.subscribedTowns" bs-typeahead>
```

Below is the js:

```
var oostApp = angular.module('oostApp', ['mgcrea.ngStrap']);

oostApp.controller('SearchController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.data = {};

  $scope.data.cityState = '';

  $scope.data.subscribedTowns = {

    '54bd7820104d630153f62a06': {
      id: "54bd7820104d630153f62a06", label: "Bloomfield, CT", name: "Bloomfield", state: "CT"
    },

    '54bd7829104d630153f66082': {
      id: "54bd7829104d630153f66082", label: "Manchester, CT", name: "Manchester", state: "CT"
    }

  };

}]);
```

Below is the plunker:
http://embed.plnkr.co/XFMMUfTLmmvNXn2quO0Y

The error I get in Google chrome is

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at i (typeahead.js:259)
    at typeahead.js:259
    at l.promise.then.F (angular.js:11573)
    at l.promise.then.F (angular.js:11573)
    at angular.js:11659
    at k.$get.k.$eval (angular.js:12702)
    at k.$get.k.$digest (angular.js:12514)
    at k.$get.k.$apply (angular.js:12806)
    at angular.js:1447
    at Object.d [as invoke] (angular.js:3966)
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why you are using objects within an object and giving it the object id as a key while the object has the same id value in it. I think it is better to use an array and this might also create that error you are getting. The id value is included in every object, so there is no need to duplicate this as a key for the whole object. It's easier and faster to iterate over an array and the online examples on AngularStrap also use an array.
Source: https://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/typeaheads#typeaheads

This way you can go in the object directly and get all the values you need to work with the typeahead from AngularStrap.

Here is a possible solution:
http://plnkr.co/edit/5AewKg?p=preview

The `undefined function` I am getting now is from Plunker. I don't get this every time and it's never there when I test the code local. Let me know if it works for you. Typing **B** will trigger both possibilities.

Another small note:

```
angular.module('appName', []); // This is the angular module setter
angular.module('appName'); // This is the angular getter
```

Source: github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#modules